# How to calculate Calories in KCal from time and distance running

Tags: calories

I am working on a school project and I need a simple equation for calculating the number of Calories burnt when running from time(in milliseconds, could be seconds, minutes, and so on..) and distance(in meters, could be in kilometers, and so on..). Do I need a bodymass? if yes it can be included. Can somebody help me? I've spent 3 days of googling and didn't find a proper answer.

Comment: You might have more luck if you  were able to include heart-rate data.

Comment: Hi @Niall, one’s heart rate has little to no bearing on their energy expenditure, as one’s heart rate can vary depending on many factors. Greg Doucette elaborates on this point: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SLkCSkhgKp8

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You just need to have avarage HR and time

One of the more standard and most accurate ways to calculate the equation is to use the calorie expenditure formula below .  It comes from the Journal of Sports Sciences and provides a formula for each gender.

Men use the following formula:

Calories Burned = [(Age x 0.2017) — (Weight x 0.09036) + (Heart Rate x 0.6309) — 55.0969] x Time / 4.184.

Women use the following formula:

Calories Burned = [(Age x 0.074) — (Weight x 0.05741) + (Heart Rate x 0.4472) — 20.4022] x Time / 4.184.

ref: http://fitnowtraining.com/2012/01/formula-for-calories-burned/

or less accurate formula:

Running (total calories spent per mile)

.75 x your weight (in lbs.)

Running (Net calories spent per mile)

.63 x your weight

Adapted from "Energy Expenditure of Walking and Running," Medicine & Science in Sport & Exercise, Cameron et al, Dec. 2004.

ref:http://www.runnersworld.com/weight-loss/how-many-calories-are-you-really-burning

Answer (score 0):

.First of all, there's no specific formula. Running involved various factors when it comes to calorie consumption. Like, at what speed you are running, what's your weight and what's the wind resistance also the slope . There are other details, but if we keep in mind the above, you can get a rough estimate. Remember, those treadmills that give the results of your calorie expense after running, just do an estimate, it's not accurate. Your calorie expenditure could be anywhere between +/- 20% of what the results show.

Having said that, you need to start from the amount of force your legs generate during impact on the ground. That multipled by distance you run, is the work done of calories burned. It's not that easy as the distance has to be liner. Physics says work = force X displacement, which means if you are running in a circle and end up at the same point, your displacement is 0 so work done is 0, correct? Doesn't make sense when you are so beat after running 20 rounds of the soccer ground.  So for the sake of your ease, just keep it limited to the distance you cover.

If you are running up the slope, your work done will be against gravity. Instead of distance, you need to consider the height you have reached above the point where  you started and multiply it with your weight. That's the potential energy gained by your body, or calories lost.

So, it will all give you a rough estimate, not anything absolute. Also, there are several factors like breathing, chemical reactions in your body that's not taken into account, because body burns calories when when you are at rest. So, I'd say it's complex and differes for every human. If you go by physics that I explained above, remember, that the margin of error would be around 20% or even higher.

Note: Dont fall for scams that claim they can get the exact count of your body's calorie expenses. Those products are just to make money, and to trap people with limited knowledge about how the stuffs work. Wish you the best.